# ajax fetch into div, div not taking size

Tags: jquery

Using jquery, i fetch a data from php to div

```
$.post(url.php?info="+$('#info').val() // rest of code

$('#information').show().html($(response).fadeIn('slow'));
```

i set in css #information as

```
width: 290px; border: 2px solid #000;
```

Any idea why height isn't automatically set? do i have to do something?

i am new in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks ok without seeing more code or a working example of your problem.

You should take a look at the div using firebug or some other web tool to see if maybe there is some other overriding style that is setting the height to a fixed size.